# Finding first instance of one list in a second list

Tags: python, list, numpy, set

I have two lists.

The first list is already sorted (by some other criteria) such that the earlier in the list, the better.

```
sortedList = ['200', '050', '202', '203', '206', '205', '049', '047', '042', '041', '043', '044', '046', '045', '210', '211', '306', '302', '308', '309', '311', '310', '221', '220', '213', '212']
```

The second list is a list of allowed values:

```
allowedList = ['001','002','003','004','005','006','007','008','009','010','203','204','205','206','207','212','213','215','216']
```

I would like to select the highest sorted value that exists in the allowedList, and I'm only coming up with silly ways of doing this. Things like this:

```
import numpy as np
temp = []
for x in allowedList:
    temp.append(sortedList.index(x))
np.min(temp)
```

There has to be a better way than this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions using the fact that `allowedlist` is already sorted are probably more efficient (and using a `set`, they certainly are - linear time vs quadratic), but for completeness only, your existing solution can be shortened a lot and the temporary list eliminated:

```
min(allowedList, key=sortedList.index)
```

This uses Python's [built-in `min` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min), rather than the one from numpy - `np.min` is mainly only useful if you're using them with numpy arrays; there is no need for it when using lists.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you could do this without numpy

```
>>> sorted_list = ['200', '050', '202', '203', '206', '205', '049', '047', '042', '041', '043', '044', '046', '045', '210', '211', '306', '302', '308', '309', '311', '310', '221', '220', '213', '212']
>>> allowed_list = ['001','002','003','004','005','006','007','008','009','010','203','204','205','206','207','212','213','215','216']
>>> allowed_set = set(allowed_list)
>>> next((x for x in sorted_list if x in allowed_set), None)
'203'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
allowedSet = set(allowedList)
i, a = next(((i, a) for i, a in enumerate(sortedList) if a in allowedSet), (-1, None))
```

`i` is index of the first such element (3), `a` is that element ('203').

If, in any case, the two lists have no common elements, `i = -1` and `a = None`, which you can modify yourself.